# setWeek year detection

Tags: datejs

Have a look at the year after setWeek

```
d = Date.today() 
Wed Dec 26 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) 
d.getWeek() 
52 
d.setWeek(52) 
Mon Dec 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Anyone knows what this is about? Have I misinterpreted how the setWeek function should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an issue in the `datejs` tracker with this same problem. It's from 2011, though it's still marked as *new*: [setWeek issue](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=139)

So regarding yor question of "Have I misinterpreted how the setWeek function should work?" I would say that it's a bug in the `jdate` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the datejs source code you will see that `setWeek` will always move to the Monday of the target week `n`:

```
Date.prototype.setWeek = function (n) {
  return this.moveToDayOfWeek(1).addWeeks(n - this.getWeek());
};
```

see: [datejs:  svn/trunk/src/core.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/core.js#408)